# Finding the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}+ \sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Find the Limit

$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\sqrt{x^{2}-1}+ \sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$.

If you could explain it, it would be better to understand what happen and how

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{x^2 - 1} = \sqrt{x + 1} \cdot \sqrt{x - 1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the broken formatting right, the problem is as follows

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}+\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$$

Notice that you can write $\sqrt{x^2-1} = \sqrt{x-1}\cdot\sqrt{x+1}$.

Now one can factor the numerator and cancel the denominator to get the answer as $\sqrt{2} +1$.

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), answering questions without context is not advised.

Comment: I agree with Gary. What's the purpose of telling OP the answer ($\sqrt{2} + 1$), other than that you've done his homework for him?

Comment: Well I did pretty much give him the method for the answer and guided him through the process, so to me it makes sense for me to give him the answer so he can be sure. But I won't argue against it, I will simply write "I hope you can take it from here" next time, and avoid answering questions without context overall. Apologies.